# CQS: Who is responsible for data caching and when?

Tags: domain-driven-design, command-query-separation, data-caching

When and who should be responsible for caching data into local data store from API GET requests in DDD architecture with CQS based use cases?

---

**First thing that comes to mind:**

Initiate a **Query** to get some data from local data store and if it is empty, fetch required data from API -> cache it into local data store -> return it

This solution does not seem to follow CQS correctly because **Queries** should not alter data store (or can they?).

---

**Second thing that comes to mind:**

Execute a **Command** to fetch fresh data from API -> update data store -> raise a data updated event -> event handler listens for data updated events and executes new **Query** to get fresh data

---

Second solution seems to follow CQS pattern better, tho I am not sure if any of these solutions are by any means correct way of handling data caching in CQS based architecture.

Answer (score 2):

The first option isn't, to my mind, any "bigger" of a violation of CQS/CQRS as the second.  The query isn't altering authoritative state (e.g. a DDD aggregate), it's just copying it into a cache.  It does require cache invalidation.

The second is questionable because a query results in a command (it's sometimes reasonable to treat a query as a read-only command (provided the query limits itself to a single aggregate) in order to have a stronger consistency guarantee).

A better approach to my mind is to have a hybrid of the two:

- Queries are served from the cache if possible
- When commands result in updates to aggregates, events are published (ideally listing the aggregates which changed)
- Event handler listens for update events and invalidates cache based on which aggregates have changed.

A further evolution of this would be event sourcing, where the updates are the events and the queries only get served by a read model fed by the events.